# Illegal string offset 'error'

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

I am new to cakephp and php and im trying to save a file in a folder after uploading it. I am following this tutorial http://www.tuxradar.com/content/cakephp-tutorial-build-file-sharing-application.

I have this code:

```
    function uploadFile() {    
        $file = $this->data['Upload']['file'];  
  if ($file["error"] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {  
    $id = String::uuid();  
    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], APP.'uploads'.DS.$id)) {  
      $this->data['Upload']['id'] = $id;  
      $this->data['Upload']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');  
      $this->data['Upload']['filename'] = $file['name'];  
      $this->data['Upload']['filesize'] = $file['size'];  
      $this->data['Upload']['filemime'] = $file['type'];  
      return true;  
    }  
  }  
  return false;  
}
```

and it is giving me this error: `Illegal string offset 'error'`
I tried this `"var_dump($file["error"]);"`
and it is returning `string(1) "1"`
What is my problem and how can i solve it.
Thanks

Comment: Look in $this->data['Upload'] or check array key 'upload'.

Comment: I just tried to remove ['Upload']['file'] and var_dumb is giving me array(2) { ["Upload"]=> array(3) { ["title"]=> string(2) "mm" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["file"]=> string(24) "15 You Don't Know Me.mp3" } ["User"]=> array(1) { ["User"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } } }. Now i have a problem with: Undefined index: error

Comment: did you used `<?php echo $this->Form->create('Upload', array('type' => 'file'));?>` ?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that because the download didn't cause any error this is why the error index isn't present, this is why i suggest you to write in your test :

```
if(isset($file['error']) && $file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
  //your code here
}
```

I hope that i was helpful.

Comment: unfortunately i tried it and im still getting the same error. It giving the error: Undefined index: for error, name, size, type, tmp_name. I am guessing it is because they are not part of the array. I think i need to try a different function.

Comment: The condition in this answer will never pass.  Something can't be both not set (first part of the condition) _and_ equal to something (second part). Remove the negation from the first part of the condition.